# T4 template generated files are not nested under .tt file

Tags: templates, .net-core, nested, t4, auto-generate

Since I wanted a generate multiple files using T4 templates, I have added a T4 template file to a Class Library (.NET Core) project (.net Core 2.1).

[image]

I added following code to T4 template.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
for (Int32 i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
#>
Content <#= i #>
<#
  // End of file.
  SaveOutput("Content" + i.ToString() + ".txt");
}
#>
<#+
private void SaveOutput(string outputFileName) {
  string templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
  string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory, outputFileName);
  File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString()); 
  this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, this.GenerationEnvironment.Length);
}
#>
```

As expected, this created 5 text files.

[image]

However, the files created from the template are not nested to the "Generated.Files.tt" file. How do we nested these files under "Generated.Files.tt" so if I expand the tt file, I would like to see the generated files.

Answer (score 1):

`this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, this.GenerationEnvironment.Length);`is what removes the output to the childnode. In that template manually create the files and write output to it in your SaveOutput method.

Just remove that method and output is automatically generated in a childnode.

Example:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
for (Int32 i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
#>
Content <#= i #>
<#
}
#>
```

Just removing `this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, this.GenerationEnvironment.Length);` will cause the template to generate a childnode, but you're still writing to files yourself then.

[Here](https://epsicode.com/2019/03/28/t4-beginner-tutorial/) is a basic tutorial with some explanation.